# Sharing a global variable throughout packages

Tags: variables, go, global, package

So I have a SQL pointer (`*sql.DB`) that needs shared throughout packages.

For example:

"`./main.go`" has a global variable "`db`" that needs to be shared with a package in "`./another/package.go`".
How could one achieve sharing variables without passing function parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the global variable is exported (meaning its name starts with an uppercase letter: `Db *sql.DB`), you can access it in another package through its full name:

```
package.name.Db
```

But the alternative to global variable is dependency injection, as in using the [**inject** framework](http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/boot2docker.html) to initialize the correct db.

See "[Dependency Injection with Go](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/dependency-injection-with-go/)":

> The `inject` library is the result of this work and our solution.
>   It uses `struct` tags to enable injection, allocates memory for concrete types, and supports injection for interface types as long as they’re unambiguous.
>   It also has some less often used features like named injection. Roughly, our naive example above now looks something like this:

```
type AppLoader struct {
  MongoService mongo.Service `inject:""`
}

func (l *AppLoader) Get(id uint64) *App {
  a := new(App)
  l.MongoService.Session().Find(..).One(a)
  return a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to VonC's question is to provide a constructor - e.g.

```
// package datastore
var db *sql.DB

func NewDB(host, port string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    // Simplified example
    conn, err := sql.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    db = conn
    return conn, nil
}

// package main
func main() {
    db, err := datastore.NewDB("localhost", "5432")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Now you can use it here, and/or in your datastore package
}
```

It's typically good practice to use constructors to initialize a package's requirements, and/or pass in a pre-initialized object - e.g. `datastore.NewFromExisting(db)` to pass in a pool you've already created.

Where possible your `package main` should simply be an entry point for other packages and should try to avoid consuming things on its own.